# Postgresql with Laravel: Filter Json field with substring

Tags: laravel, postgresql, orm

I am having a table say `post_media` which has a JSON column `metadata`. Now, `metadata` JSON has a field says `originalName` which has the full name of file/media eg: test.png. 
All kind of files are there like: .png, .jpeg, .mov, .pdf, .ppt, .doc and etc
I want to select find only png files from the table. There is no separate column for the extension.

I've tried it with virtual columns using `as` and `mutator`. But `where`  is not working with virtual columns.

```
$post_media = PostMedia::select(\DB::raw("metadata->>'originalName' from '\.([^\.]*)$') as file_extention"))->where('file_extention', 'png')->get();
```

I want all PNG extension files. Any idea?

Comment: Few things to note down. If you create virtual column you can't put that virtual column into where condition. You can try with having.

Comment: @narayansharma91, Not working with having. Showing same error: - `SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "file_extension" does not exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is just put your regex condition on where condition like below.

```
$post_media = PostMedia::select(\DB::raw("metadata->>'originalName' from '\.([^\.]*)$') as file_extention"))->whereRaw("metadata->>'originalName' from '\.([^\.]*)$')='png'")->get();
```

It will help you.

Comment: Enjoy @SahilGupta